# How to get both cover photo and profile photo from Facebook via JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to get both Cover photo and Profile photo from Facebook in a single call via JavaScript SDK (Facebook API version 2.5). I got cover photo and profile photo in separate ajax call.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: edit description and add details about which api you used. it will be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick test, works fine:

```
/me?fields=cover,picture.type(large)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String profileImgUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + fbId + "/picture";
```

Comment: that will only get the profile picture, but not the cover